# Why was this question marked as rude/spam?

Tags: discussion, bug, specific-question, rude-or-abusive

I recently encountered a question that was clearly off-topic (it was asking about why a particular contest didn't allow external libraries, which should be directed to the people holding the contest rather than us). It was kind of a rant in disguise, but not so much of a rant that I'd flag it as Rude/Abusive.

That being said, it was eventually deleted by a moderator after it was closed for being off-topic:

[image]

However, the main page shows it being marked as Spam or Rude/Abusive. Was it actually marked as Rude/Abusive, or is this a bug? If so, why was this considered rude (rather than merely off-topic)? Also, if it was, in fact, marked as rude, why wasn't the 100 rep hard penalty applied?

[image]

Here's a [link to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353150/unallowed-libraries-for-code-jam-programming) for 10k+ users.

Comment: I suspect that it was in error. Mods make mistakes (such as wrong button clicks), just like the rest of us. As much as some believe otherwise, they *are* only human.

Comment: Probably a mod deleted the question in response to R/A flag instead of declining it. I doubt it's a bug. Also, mods do not see this message so they might not even realize sometimes that marking the flag as helpful leads to confusing messages for the rest of us

Comment: Probably that the question is deleted WHRAOEUL there's at least one spam flag on it. In that case it will be displayed like that while the penalty is not applied.

Comment: When just one user has flagged it as rude/abusive, that banner will show, if the post is deleted before the flag is handled. The user will not get the penalty unless it was deleted as rude/abusive by 6 red flags by regular users or one red flag by a moderator. The user does not see this message at all. They're completely unaware of the banner. I know because I've tried that on one of my own Answers :-)

Comment: That's still slightly odd to me - I don't see any particular reason to flag this as Rude/Abusive, it's just off topic.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Oh, I'm sorry. I do make mistakes, so much to click.

Comment: Minor point: in your screenshot, you've redacted the moderator name, which is fine, but somewhat moot since you shared a link to the post.

Comment: A single person had flagged it as spam, and when the post was deleted by a moderator, that one flag triggered the content-hiding setting for spam. Content hiding is independent from penalties for red flags, which only apply when 6 such flags are cast (or when a moderator cast such a flag).

Comment: It’s possible that this post did indeed include spam, which the OP then removed during the 5 minute grace period, so no revision history of it is available. However, I remember a discussion about flags immediately ending the grace period. But maybe someone flagged it a second after the edit and didn’t notice or forgot to retract the flag. Just speculating.

Comment: IMO it's not abusive, but it is rude.

Comment: wow, probably people voted to get it dleted

Comment: @user202729: WHRAOEUL?

Comment: Why does the reason matter? The garbage is cleared, and that's the point at the end of the day.

Comment: @IanKemp because spam gets routed to SpamRam and the user's IP will be marked as a spam account even though they didn't spam.

Comment: Mods make mistakes, they’re only human. We make mistakes and get suspended from reviewing. Sounds fair.

Comment: @IanKemp As long as it doesn't result in undeserved sanctions against the user. The post *wasn't* rude, just off-topic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It only needs one red flag (spam or rude/abusive) to cause that effect.

If you feel a post is red-flagged deleted incorrectly, raise a custom moderator flag explaining that a red flag was present on the post and that it got marked helpful due to the mod delete vote.

The mod will then revisit and if they agree there was no red-flagable content they will undelete the post, clear the flag and then re-delete (they can't clear flags while the post is deleted).

Not much else we can do about it, except using those red flags responsibly.

Comment: Minor nit: Actually, we do have the option to clear spam/rude/abusive (red) flags while the post is deleted. However, if the post is deleted and/or locked, then clearing the red flags automatically undeletes and unlocks the post, with no option not to have the undelete/unlock happen. If we want the post to end in the deleted state, then we need to re-delete it after the red flags are cleared.

Comment: The last sentence "Doesn't it make sense?" sounds kinda rude to me tbh

Comment: @wyphan that doesn’t make it a rude or offensive post. If you can edit the post to improve it the flag doesn’t apply. See [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) for more information.

Comment: @wyphan Assume the best if you have no proof of the worst.

Comment: @wyphan - How so? The OP presented their reasoning, and then solicited feedback with this question. It's a rhetorical question, most like, but that hardly makes it rude.

Comment: Point of order. Are all flags red?

Comment: @wyphan the only rudeness I could see in the question "Doesn't it make sense" would be if the person were a native English speaker and said it in an aggressive manner. My own read on this is that the person isn't a native English speaker, so was intending something like the more neutral "Does that make sense?" not understanding the more subtle aspects of the potential connotations within exactly how it was phrased.

Comment: @Joshua only two of them, now clarified in the answer.

Comment: Seems like a mod took your advice! :-)